# Can a disassembler achieve 100% accuracy?

Tags: disassembly

I know that correctly disassemble a COST binary is still an issue. But, given the symbols and debug infomation, can a disassembler achieve a 100% accuracy in disassembling any binary? If no, I would like to know what are the failing cases.

Answer (score 0):

Because on some platforms, disassembling may not have only a single solution. Check out this code, for example:

```
mov rax, 0x1111111111E8
call get_eip
get_eip:
pop rax
sub rax, 13
jmp rax
```

Assembled into the following:

```
48 B8 E8 11 11 11 11 11 00 00 E8 00 00 00 00 58 48 2D 0D 00 00 00 FF E0
```

The `jmp rax` will actually jump to the middle of the `mov rax, 0x1111111111E8` opcode, specifically to the bytes:  `E8 11 11 11 11` which form a valid relative call opcode.

So, how do you disassembly the above binary? :)

On other platforms (such as `ARM`), the value or `eip` (`pc` on ARM) determine the architecture. On some `ARM`s, having the `LSB` of `PC` on means you're running `thumb` mode (a different instruction set), while opcodes are always 4 bytes long (on `aarch64`. On `ARMv7`, they're 4 bytes long on regular mode and 2 bytes long on `thumb` mode iirc).

However, in practice, most code is produced by compilers, where such nasty tricks can't take place. So compiler code is actually easy disassembled.